# bash: dynamic string for curl

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to get files from specific folder, load them with curl and get result to variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
FILES=*
for f in $FILES
do
  core=$f
  #echo "curl -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" --data-binary @$f http://v-cdh-master:8983/solr/$core/update/json?commit=true"
  result=$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -s --data-binary @$f http://v-cdh-master:8983/solr/$core/update/json?commit=true)
done
```

The result of running this script is

```
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

If I remove comment from echo string I could see the valid url like this

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @affiliates_multival http://v-cdh-master:8983/solr/affiliates_multival/update/json?commit=true
```

Which works perfect when I copy/paste it to terminal.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` in the URL causes the entire argument to be treated as a glob, which is not matching a file. Since you have the `nullglob` option enabled, the word is removed from the call to `curl`. Quoting the argument, as you do with the `echo` command, will resolved the problem by preventing pathname generation.

```
result=$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -s --data-binary @"$f" "http://v-cdh-master:8983/solr/$core/update/json?commit=true")
```